# Was Bramhadev worshipped in treta and dwapara yuga?

Tags: worship, brahma, yuga, vyasa

We know Bramhadev isn't worshipped in Kaliyuga. Are there any evidence on Bramhadev being worshipped in Tretayuga and Dwaparayuga except Mahamuni Vyasa meditating on Bramhadev before writing Mahabharata?